# How do you get the AB Destroyer in Saints Row IV?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I looked all over the Airport but couldn't find it. Are there any prerequisites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my game, the AB Destroyer is parked in front of one of the hangars. If you look at the runway that goes east to west, north of this runway is a set of 5 buildings visible on your map.

The western building is the control tower, and there are 4 hangers to the east.  The AB Destroyer was parked in front of the first hanger east of the control tower.

I'm not aware of any prerequisites, although in my game I do have 100% completion.  The game is pretty liberal about giving out powerful vehicles, though.  Normally, if there is an unlock condition, the vehicle will be given to you in a pack and immediately summonable via your phone.

You might have to destroy the Zinyak statue on top of the terminal (near the Snipes 57) to unlock it.

Comment: Found it! The weird thing, though, is that I didn't see it the first time (or any of the other times I flew past the place). I looked in the same place, gave up and destroyed the nearby Zinyak statue, and came back to take a screenshot to make sure it was the right place - and that's when I saw it.

Comment: @ARADPLAUG, that might be it, but I'd be willing to bet it just sometimes doesn't spawn there.  I found it on the first try, though, so maybe I just got lucky :)